# Сравнение двух файлов, не тривиальное

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два файла

1

```
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
```

2

```
11111111111 текст1
22222222222 текст2
33333333333 текст999
44444444444 текст34
55555555555 текст567
```

Хочу сделать так, что бы 1 файл сравнивался со 2 и если во втором есть совпадение, печаталась строка второго файла полностью.
Т.е. если у меня сейчас файл 1 это

```
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
```

то на выходе хочу что бы было в принте:

```
11111111111 текст1
22222222222 текст2
33333333333 текст999
```

С помощью поиска текста в строке я это сделать могу вот таким способом:

```
i = 0
with open('2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        list_words = line.split()
        i = i+1
        if '11111111111' in line:
            print(line, end='')
        if '22222222222' in line:
            print(line, end='')
```

Как сделать, что бы сравнивались оба файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно так же.

Открываем оба файла, ищем каждую строку первого во втором.

```
with open('1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    lines_file_1 = file1.readlines()
    with open('2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file2:
        lines_file_2 = file2.readlines()
        for line1 in lines_file_1:
            line1 = line1.strip()
            for line2 in lines_file_2:
                line2 = line2.strip()
                if line1 in line2:
                    print(line2)
```

Comment: Пустой вывод к сожалению... Попробовал уже разные варианты вашего предложения

Comment: это потому что перевод строки тоже учитывался. Исправил.